# Combining similar names and counting distinct from a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, data-manipulation

I am attempting to combine rows with similar names within a single column. The data I am using has some clients listed with the same name:

```
| Client_Column | Address |
|   XYZ ISD     | 1 Drive |
|   XYZ ISD     | 2 Drive |
|   XYZ ISD     | 3 Drive |
```

However, there are some records where the same client has a distinct, but similar name with an alternate address:

```
| Client_Column  |  Address | 
|    ABC Inc.    | 101 Lane | 
|  ABC Inc. - P1 | 102 Lane | 
|  ABC Inc. - P2 | 103 Lane |
```

I would like to count the total number of distinct addresses for each client in the table. So in this example, XYZ ISD and ABC Inc. would each have 3 unique addresses. How can I adjust my script so that I can achieve this result?

I think I need to use SUM to aggregate the total, but I am not sure how. I am able to count the addresses for clients with the exact same name with accuracy, but the ones with only similar names display a single record for AddressCount.

Here is the script:

```
SELECT ClientName, COUNT(Address) AS AddressCount
FROM tableA 
GROUP BY ClientName
ORDER BY AddressCount
```

Result:

```
| Client_Column | AddressCount |
|    Blue LLC   |      15      | 
|    PSC Parts  |      14      |
|    ABC Inc.   |       1      |
| ABC Inc. - P1 |       1      |
| ABC Inc. - P2 |       1      |
```

Comment: Well you have to define what is "similar". How would you define this, explicitly, in a manner which could be coded for? Would ABC Inc. - P1 = xcd ABC Inc. - P1 etc? We need some business logic here. Or, does similar names always have a `- L12` or something similar on the end?

Comment: You going to need another table or column that references that the variations of each Client_Column mean.  ABC Inc.  <>  ABC Inc.  - P1. In my experience, whenever there's a variation like this, it's best to create a standard on naming conventions rather than letting SQL do the dirty work

Comment: The name doesn't always have something at the end, but the name will always have the core of the company name. So Walmart #301 will be the same customer as Neighborhood Walmart #2503 because they both contain the similar string 'walmart'

Comment: And what if two companies contained the name Neighborhood... what would you do then? Attribute it to WalMart and the other company? I hope you see how impossible this will become

Comment: @OP, If you are willing to make that assumption on your end, then clean up the DB to have standard naming conventions. Create another column that will display Walmart#301, Wal-Mart2923, Walmart INC -Part2 to be "Walmart:. Do a count on your new column instead.